# Filling std::vector<byte> from ID3DBLob

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am compiling a shader file using D3DCompile2() which fill a ID3DBlob with the compiled byte code.

But I need to fill the compiled buffer from the ID3DBlob to a std::vector container. The ID3DBlob has methods to get the buffer pointer and size of the buffer as follows:

LPVOID GetBufferPointer();

SIZE_T GetBufferSize();

How can I fill the std::vector with the buffer in ID3DBlob in best possible way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to interpret "best possible way", but this is a pretty clean way of doing it, syntactically speaking.

```
using buffer_t = std::vector<unsigned char>;

auto *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(d3dblob->GetBufferPointer());
auto  n = d3dblob->GetBufferSize();
buffer_t buff;

buff.reserve(n);
std::copy(p, p+n, std::back_inserter(buff))
```

Comment: You could accept this as an answer if it has helped :)